# How to delete from SQL Database

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to write code to delete a transaction from an SQL database. The function below adds a deposit and another deletes it from the SQL database. When I try running it, it leads to an SQLLiteException from this line:

```
TransactionDAO.removeTransaction(int, String) line: 154




public void addDeposit(int accountID, String transName, long efDate,
            double amount) {
        ContentValues tran = new ContentValues();
        tran.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_ACCOUNTID, accountID);
        tran.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_TRANSNAME, transName);
        tran.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_ENTEREDTIMESTAMP, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis());
        tran.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_EFFECTIVETIMESTAMP, efDate);
        tran.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
        tran.put(SQLHelper.COLUMN_COMMITTED, 1);
        database.insert(SQLHelper.TABLE_TRANSACTION, transName, tran);
    }
public void removeTransaction(int accountID, String transName) {
        ContentValues tran = new ContentValues();
        database.delete(SQLHelper.TABLE_TRANSACTION, transName, null);
    }
```

I really have no idea how to solve this problem. Im confused on how to find the exact row in an SQL database. That is probably the reason for the error.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 1):

According to [public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), where the second argument is a where *clause*, you should use

```
database.delete(SQLHelper.TABLE_TRANSACTION, String.format("%s=?", SQLHelper.COLUMN_TRANSNAME), {transName});
```